# How do I need to localize an image?

Tags: objective-c, macos, localization

I have a code to set an image to an NSImageView. The name of the image depends on the item of the selection.

```
id selectedItem = [_sidebarOutlineView itemAtRow:[_sidebarOutlineView selectedRow]];
[noDataImage setImage:[NSImage imageNamed:[selectedItem stringByAppendingString:@".png"]]];
```

But since my "selectedItem" gets translated, it doesn't find the image anymore.

Let say the "selectedItem" in the programming language is just "Favorites", then it will set an image that has the name "Favorites.png".

But now I am using the Dutch language so the "selectedItem" is automatically changing to "Favorieten", which the image needs to be set to "Favorieten.png".

But it can't find "Favorieten.png" cause it doesn't exist.

Is there a way to solve this? Cause if I would just copy the image and rename it for every possible language, it would take a lot of space.

Comment: You **should not** copy-paste images with different names.
Instead, try to use same key - that you use for String localization - for image name.
Say your key for Favorite is "common_favorite" and also use this name for image.

Comment: I think, you'd better store some value in your `selectedItem` called `imageName` or `localizedKey`, where you'll store imageName string.

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov if i use “NSLocalalizedString (@“FavorietenImage.png” , @“Favorite Image”)  and then in the Localizable.strings file, translate “FavorietenImage.png” to “Favorite.png” it should solve the problem?

Comment: Yes, try that..

Comment: @AlekseyPotapov It works. It's a really weird way but yeah it works.